# squid:S2583 – Sonarqube false positive when using switch

Tags: java, sonarqube

For the following contrived example (the real code actually makes sense, I promise), Sonarqube 5.3 with Java plugin 2.10 will give me the dreaded “Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"”:

```
public String sonarLint(DayOfWeek dow) {
    boolean one = false;
    boolean two = false;
    switch (dow) {
    case MONDAY:
        one = true;
    case TUESDAY:
        two = true;
        break;
    default:
        // nothing
    }
    return one && two ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

As far as I can see, when `dow` is `MONDAY`, the condition is true, while it’s false otherwise (IntelliJ agrees, BTW, telling me that `two` whill always be true when it is evaluated at all). Did I hit a bug in Sonarqube here?

Answer (score 0):

Sonar should report the error for missing break statement as well.

**Switch cases should end with an unconditional "break" statement**(Squid:S128).

Once you have the break statement in both the cases, then statement will never be executed as true.

Comment: That’s true, but it’s got nothing to do with my question at all. The real code looks a bit different, as noted.

Comment: What are all values your DayOfWeek Enum has? If there are only two different values that it can have (MONDAY, TUESDAY), then it will report the same error that your condition will always be evaluated to true.

Comment: `java.time.DayOfWeek` contains, rather not surprisinly, 7 enum values. Even if it didn’t, the paths for `MONDAY` and `TUESDAY` are sufficiently different.